# rendering a bootstrap modal using partial view and ajax call make all fields not editable(event the modal himself)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

[here is the bootstrap modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT0dh.png)I Have successfully rendered a partial view containing a bootstrap modal in a view . 
the problem is when i show the modal all the content are not editable any more  even the content of the modal .

//View

```
[@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function editRole(id) {
            if (!id) { return false; }
            tools.AjaxPost("/Roles/Edit", { id: id }).always(function (data) {
                tools.setHtmlElement("edit", data.responseText);
                tools.showModal("roleModal");
            });
        }
    </script>
}

//partial view 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="roleModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">تعديل الدور</h4>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}][1]
```

Comment: Is the partial view loaded on page-load or returned with an ajax request? if it is loaded on page-load, then why do you need a partial view?

Comment: returned with ajax request . i am doing my modal strongly typed (object)

Comment: @ShivaBrahma what happens when you close modal, does it work then ?

Comment: i could not close the modal @satsvelke in have to refresh the page . but if you are asking to check if the problem is from the modal . i can assure you that it is indeed

Comment: @ShivaBrahma I think the problem is with z-index property for modal, can you give or change z-index in CSS and see if it works

Comment: @satsvelke i have tried to change index (higher and lower). nothing changes